# Is there an all-in-one build system for dynamic react applications?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Build systems like next.js, razzle and back-pack seem really helpful, but based on examples I've found and the default applications they generate, they seem to be geared toward Server Side Rendering. Are there similar build systems that can (or can the ones mentioned here) be used to build dynamic react applications w/ node.js back-ends?

I'm hoping to find one I can run out of the box that will watch back-end and front-end code and refresh on a change to either. I know I can find a webpack or gulp script to start with and customize it, but I like the idea of a tool like the above that is just one command.

**Edit**

I need to deploy my front-end to Google Cloud Storage, so I don't want any server-side rendering at all.

Comment: Doesn't next.js `npm run dev` do just that?

Comment: Creating a sample next.js app and going through the tutorials, my understanding was that the UI is rendered on the server side. I'm going for a browser app that is compiled to a single just file at build time (standard SPA). If you can point to any examples of next.js being used for that, it would be very helpful.

Comment: It's renderer server side on initial page load, then it's classic SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export your next.js app as long as you only use features supported by export.

From the documentation:

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#static-html-export

> This is a way to run your Next.js app as a standalone static app without any Node.js server. The export app supports almost every feature of Next.js including dynamic urls, prefetching, preloading and dynamic imports.
>
> Simply develop your app as you normally do with Next.js. Then create a custom Next.js config as shown below:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: function() {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/about': { page: '/about' },
      '/readme.md': { page: '/readme' },
      '/p/hello-nextjs': { page: '/post', query: { title: 'hello-nextjs' } },
      '/p/learn-nextjs': { page: '/post', query: { title: 'learn-nextjs' } },
      '/p/deploy-nextjs': { page: '/post', query: { title: 'deploy-nextjs' } }
    }
  }
}
```

> In that, you specify what are the pages you need to export as static HTML.
>
> Then simply run these commands:
>     next build
>     next export

On limitations:

> Limitation
>   With next export, we build HTML version of your app when you run the command next export. In that time, we'll run the getInitialProps functions of your pages.
>
> So, you could only use pathname, query and asPath fields of the context object passed to getInitialProps. You can't use req or res fields.
>
> Basically, you won't be able to render HTML content dynamically as we pre-build HTML files. If you need that, you need run your app with next start.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need server side rendering you can go for [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)